# Swift, NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject BAD_EXEC_ACCESS while Converting to JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift

[image][image]I have one Class called CompanyJson and i want to set my all my objects into the class so that i can add all class Obj into the Array and convert it to JSON array.

I am trying that but it is giving me an error while converting JSON .

### My Code Below

```
class CompanyJson
{

var ORG_CODE: String = ""
var CDATA_ORG_DESCRIPTION: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
var OBX_BTL_CODE: String = ""
var CDATA_BTL_DESCRIPTION: NSDictionary  = NSDictionary()
var ORG_STATUS: String = ""



func setCompanyJson(ORG_CODE: String,CDATA_ORG_DESCRIPTION: NSDictionary,OBX_BTL_CODE: String,CDATA_BTL_DESCRIPTION:NSDictionary,ORG_STATUS: String  ) {

     self.ORG_CODE = ORG_CODE
     self.CDATA_ORG_DESCRIPTION = CDATA_ORG_DESCRIPTION
     self.OBX_BTL_CODE = OBX_BTL_CODE
     self.CDATA_BTL_DESCRIPTION  = CDATA_BTL_DESCRIPTION
     self.ORG_STATUS = ORG_STATUS

   }


}
```

My Logic for to Iterate the Company array and fill specific array for JSON     so that i can convert it into JSON Array
—————————————————————-------------------------

```
     var companiesJson = [CompanyJson]()
     for company in self.companies
     {
        var companyJson = CompanyJson()

        var orgCData: NSDictionary = company.orgCData //NSdictionary
        var btlCData: NSDictionary = company.BtlCData  //NSdictionary

        companyJson.setCompanyJson(company.orgCode,CDATA_ORG_DESCRIPTION:orgCData,OBX_BTL_CODE:"4",CDATA_BTL_DESCRIPTION:btlCData,ORG_STATUS:"2")

        // let companyJson1 = CompanyJson(ORG_CODE: company.orgCode,CDATA_ORG_DESCRIPTION:orgCData,OBX_BTL_CODE:"",CDATA_BTL_DESCRIPTION:btlCData,ORG_STATUS:"2")

         companiesJson.append(companyJson)
        // companiesJson += [companyJson1]
      }


     var jsonError: NSError?
      var dataFinal: NSData =     NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(companiesJson, options: nil, error:  &jsonError)!   
    //Getting error over here and JsonERrror nil in debugging
    println(jsonError)
    let string = NSString(data: dataFinal, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

 --------
  orgCData:  : it show below value
 {
"#cdata-section" = “ABSBS”;
 }
 {
  "#cdata-section" = "BISMARK TECNOLOGIA";
 }

btlCData : it show below value
 {
"#cdata-section" = "Advogados/Contabilidade";
}
```

Can someone please recode a bit or explian me what i am doing wronge?
I am struggling from Last 2 days.
I appreaciate any help!

Thanks,

Comment: Did the same as you say but it not reaches to the println(jsonError) ..I gives me the error in above line only.Please suggest?

Comment: have attached the Snapshot too and edited my question

Comment: Good edits. At this time I am suspicious of your `companyJson`, especially `company.orgCData` and `company.BtlCData`. What data types do those dictionaries contain?

Comment: Edited my Code with Output.. Right now i am just setting whole CData string to NSDictionary...like..  var orgCData: NSDictionary = NSDictionary() .Please have a look and suggets?

Comment: Why you do the forced unwrapping? Ofc if an error occurs the NSData? will be nil and you get an ugly exception.

Comment: 0x434D53, Ok removed that..But it is giving me the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it

```
    var newCompanyArray:Array<AnyObject> = []
    var dict = Dictionary<String,String>()
    var jsonError: NSError?

    print("loadCompaniesFromSynch >> Companies Count  \(self.companies.count)")

    for cmp in self.companies {
        dict["ORG_CODE"] = cmp.orgCode
        dict["ORG_DESCRIPTION"] = cmp.orgDescription
        dict["OBX_B1L_CODE"] = cmp.orgBtlCode
        dict["1TL_DESCRIPTION"] = cmp.orgBtlDescription
        dict["1RG_STATUS"] = cmp.orgStatus

        newCompanyArray.append(dict)
    }

    print(NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(newCompanyArray))
    var dataFinal:NSData =  NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(newCompanyArray, options: nil, error:  &jsonError)!
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont do the forced unwrapping in

`var dataFinal: NSData =     NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(companiesJson, options: nil, error:  &jsonError)!`

The documentation says, that if an error occurs, `dataWithJSONObject` returns `nil`. If you force unwrap here, you will crash in case of an error before you can inspect the `NSError`.
So remove the `!` and check for the error first.

Comment: 0x434D53, var jsonError: NSError?
        var dataFinal: NSData =  NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(companiesJson, options: nil, error:  &jsonError)  (It is suggesting me to put "!"

Comment: Because you say the datatype is NSData, not NSData?, juist `let dataFinal = ... `

Comment: Before you continue, you should REALLY read the chapter on optionals in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: Sure will do..right now i am getting error as nil after i did same thing that u have said...

Comment: 0x434D53, added one more image for your reference..If it can help you to identify the error..?

Comment: What does `isValidJSONObject` return you?

Comment: Ohh...It is giving me False..does that mean i am not generaitn JSON properly..Or or not using datatype properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82887/discussion-between-dhaval-shah-and-0x434d53).